# deployment public keys

Tags: python, fabric

How do you guys deploy your code on your servers? I am using Fabric and Python and I would like a more automated way of pulling code from the repository through the use of public keys, but without any ops or manual intervention to set up the public keys.

Are you storing them in the code as text or in a database and generate the pk file on the fly? Any other opinions on this one ?

Answer (score 1):

This is what ssh-copy-id is for. It deploys your public key onto a machine for you. Key management isn't something I'd suggest putting into code/VCS. Each user needs to setup their keys so that the local ssh client knows to use them. We use Fabric as well, but it only uses the key that the ssh config is already telling it to.